# Choice of branch for $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ integral around $|z| = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand this question has been asked before but to make it intuitive for myself, I am trying to reason that for $|z|\geq 2$ (after change of variables to use residue at infinity) we can ensure that $1-z^2$ avoids not just zero but an entire ray out of zero. However, I am hitting a wall trying to do so. It may require some very basic inequalities here, but I'd appreciate seeing someone reason through this to understand what I am missing. One solution I had was to try to solve $1-z^2=\alpha$ for $\alpha$ along a particular cut of a branch, e.g. $\alpha < 0$ but I'm not finding the ray. If we use this strategy, we want $z^2=1-\alpha$.

Also when I evaluate this integral using contour integration, I actually found that I had to calculate $\sqrt{-1}$ when computing the residue, which made me think that the choice of branch should not include $\sqrt{-1}$ but I'm not sure if there is no reason why the calculation of residue should never require calculating along the cut of a branch.

Also adding to the question: why is it that this integrand can have a branch along $[-1,1]$? In my mind, I don't see why the branch cut is the "intersection" of branch cuts of $\sqrt{1\pm z}$.

Comment: I don't understand your language "a branch along $[-1,1]$." You can delete *either* $[-1,1]$ *or* the union of the rays $(\infty,-1]$ and $[1,\infty)$. Given the contour we wish to integrate about, we obviously want to do the former. There *is* a well-defined branch of the function defined in the complement of $[-1,1]$.  There's no problem with defining $\sqrt{-1}$. We're talking about a branch of $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z^2}$, not of $\sqrt z$. But that's a good thing for you to think about carefully

Comment: Can you explain why the branch can exclude the "intersection" of the two branch cuts, i.e. what ray are we choosing for $1-z^2$ to get that?

Comment: Rather than thinking of the function as a product, think of it as a simple composition. Note that $z\in [-1,1] \iff 1-z^2\in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks, that "if and only if" statement is exactly what I wanted. As simple as it sounds, I was just getting bogged down in finding a more "systematic" process to figure these kinds of questions out.

Comment: You're welcome. Why don't you write up a good answer now? :)